# Java script function error

Tags: javascript, html, function, web

I want the `close` and function to modify the variable `gate`, by making the padding bigger until it equals the variable `open`.  I don't know why it won't work, please help.

```
function wait() {
    setTimeout(100);
}

function close() {
    var closed = 1;
    var opened = 19;
    var gate = opened;

    while (gate !== closed) {
        gate-=1;
        gate.style.paddingTop = open'%';
        wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how `setTimeout()` works. It takes **two** arguments, and the first one is the function to call when the timer expires. It is **not** a "sleep" function.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `gate.style.paddingTop = open'%';`. `gate` is a Numeric, so `gate.style` is `undefined`.

Comment: There are a few other errors as well, like the random `open'%'` which I think you probably mean to be `open + '%'` but I'm guessing, and it's not clear what you're trying to do with `gate.style`.

Comment: Also, be careful with this: `while (gate !== closed) {`. This appears to be an infinite loop in your case.

Comment: Thank you [Pointy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) and yes [Dave Newton](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton), you are right, thank you. Thank you [Shomz](http://stackoverflow.com/users/965907/shomz), your anser was very helpfull.

Comment: You're welcome, @Mr.MikaS, that's why we're all here for! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timeouts in JS are not blocking - thing of them as running in a separate thread. There are tons of resources about how they exactly work online, so I won't get into that.

To fix your code, you can refactor is to make recursive calls:

```
var closed = 1;
var opened = 19;
var gate = opened;
var gateEl = document.getElementById('gate');

function close() {
    if (gate !== closed) {
        gate -= 1;
        gateEl.style.paddingTop = gate + '%'; // open stays the same
        setTimeout(close, 100);
    }
}
```

- make recursive calls to your `close` function
- define an element which will have its padding changed
- use `gate` instead of `open` to actually change the padding

---

Here's a live example:

```js
var closed = 1;
var opened = 19;
var gate = opened;
var gateDiv = document.getElementById('gate');

function close() {
  console.log(gate);
  if (gate > closed) {
    gate -= 1;
    gateDiv.style.paddingTop = gate + '%';
    setTimeout(close, 100);
  }
}

close();
```

```css
#gate {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="gate"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better implementation would be like this:

```js
// gate element
var gate = document.getElementById("gate");
// the space between the gate and the ground
var gap = 100;
// how many pixels/percentage you want it to move at each iteration
var increment = -2;

function close() {
  // gap = 0 means it's closed
  // as long as it's not closed run this
  if (gap > 0) {
    // decrease the gap
    gap = gap + increment;
    gate.style.top = (gap * -1) + "%";
  } else {
    // gate is closed, so we clear the interval
    clearInterval(closing);
  }
}

// a reference to interval
var closing = setInterval(close, 100);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#gate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="gate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty advanced topic! I highly recommend you read about [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s and [`async`/`await`](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html). Being experienced with asynchronous programming and JavaScript in general will also really help.

---

In the future you'll be able to use [`async`/`await`](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/) to write this pretty much the same as you did:

```
function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100)
    });
}

async function close() {
    var closed = 1;
    var opened = 19;
    var gate = opened;

    while (gate !== closed) {
        gate -= 1;
        gateEl.style.paddingTop = open + '%';
        await wait();
    }
}
```

This has a few different parts to it, so I'll go over each..

First, I fixed a couple of general issues with your code:

```
gate.style.paddingTop = open'%';
// changed to:
gateEl.style.paddingTop = open + '%';
// First, we need to join the open variable and the '%' string, so
// I add a + for that; second, gate is a number, not a DOM element,
// so I assumed there is a new variable called "gateEl" that means
// the actual element. Supply that in the actual code.
```

Then I implemented `async`/`await` into the code. This involved a few changes. I redefined the function `wait`:

```
function wait() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, 100)
    });
}
```

It looks kind of confusing but basically I'm making a new `Promise` object given a function argument. `Promise`s are the things that make `async`/`await` work. In my `wait` function, when `await wait()` is called, `resolve` is called 100 milliseconds later. `resolve` is what says that the code after `await wait()` can run.

Next, I added `async` before `function close() {...}` -- that makes `await` work inside of it.

Finally, I replaced `wait()` with `await wait()`. This changes your browser from thinking "call the `wait` function" to "call the `wait` function, and then wait until the promise <sup><sub>actually the then-able object</sub></sup> it returns to resolve." And we know that the promise resolves 100ms after `wait` is called - because we defined it to do so.

The nice thing about `await fn()` is that loops and other control structures work really well with it.